# How to add the namespace automatically on every new Page, Control added To a WebSite in VS2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, web, namespaces

How do you add the namespace automatically on every new Page, Control added To a website in VS2008?

When I add a new page, the code behind looks like this.

```
public partial class MyNewPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

}
```

I just want the page wrapped into a namespace as below:

```
namespace Project.Web
{

    public partial class MyNewPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}
    }

}
```

This is done automatically when you have a website project.

Maybe it's trivial but I haven't find out how to do this.

Comment: Does the project have a default namespace? (I have only rarely used website projects -- rather than web application projects -- and can't recall the options.)

Comment: this is a website not a website project nor application

Comment: Is the namespace the same across all the files?

Comment: rigth know no namespace is begin added but, yes i should be the same namespace in all of the website pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the namespace under "Default Namespace" in project properties, and it doesn't need to be in the code files.

Comment: Hi Scott,

this is not a web site project it doesnt have project properties only property pages. i can see they namespaces are not need, perhaps i just was used to them in my old solutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try editing the Visual Studio template file for a new page or add you own custom templates. The file you need to edit is "CodeBeside.cs" in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033\WebForm.zip" template archive, at least that's where it is on my system. Just change the class definition to match what you need; something like:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public partial class $classname$ : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You may need to replace $rootnamespace$ with the namespace you need as I'll unsure how it will be handled in a website project.

Comment: this is really not an option, since i will need to change i just wanted for a single project, and i dont want to create the template for type of Item

Comment: Fair enough, custom templates can take some time to perfect. Another option would be to record a macro which adds in the namespace in after the new page is added.